# Remove html attribute in production build

Tags: reactjs, webpack

In order to be able to write Selenium test cases for our Webpack built React app we've added data-* attributes to certain parts of the HTML elements, example:

```
<div class="Component__item___2jdnc" data-app-feature="example-id"></div>
```

We can use these to locate elements to interact with and assert on. But, in production environment I would like to have them removed. How could that be achieved?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a few babel plugins that might fit the bill for this:

- [babel-plugin-react-remove-properties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-remove-properties)
- [babel-plugin-remove-attribute](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-remove-attribute)
- [babel-plugin-remove-object-properties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-remove-object-properties)

---

#### Edit from comments

Attributes are automatically ignored if their value is `undefined`.  You can use that to your advantage and use some kind of configuration (possibly `process.env.NODE_ENV`?) and a [Higher-Order Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) to set a prop for the `data-app-feature` value only if not in production.

**HOC**

```
const appFeature = (Component, appFeature) => (props) => {
  const isRunningInProduction = configuration.isProduction // or however you want to set this
  return <Component appFeature={ isRunningInProduction ? appFeature : undefined } {...props}  />
}
```

**Component**

```
const ExampleComponent = ({appFeature}) => {
  return <div class="Component__item___2jdnc" data-app-feature={appFeature}></div>
}

export default appFeature(ExampleComponent, "example-id")
```

Comment: It was my first though, there must be build plugins for this. But I am starting to realize that I must do this at build time and therefor have different builds for different environments and I prefer to have one same build which can move from test to preprod and finally into prod.

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't want the build artifacts to change, just the elements in the users browser?  Are you using client or server side rendering?

Comment: Client rendering, so I think your HOC suggestion is the way forward.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to achieve this using webpack?

Answer (score 11):

This answer is purely for the people who use webpack for production/development builds of the application.
Do the following in **webpack.prod.config**. Ignore in **webpack.dev.config**

- Install plugin by running `npm install`[`babel-plugin-react-remove-properties`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-remove-attribute)
- Add it in babel loader configuration as follows

  ```
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          plugins: [
            ["react-remove-properties", {"properties": ["data-test-id"]}]
          ]
        }
      }],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }
  ```
- `data-test-id` is the attribute we are going to use in selenium test cases to get the elements. According to the question, it is `data-app-feature`

The same thing we can do using below plugins.

- [babel-plugin-remove-object-properties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-remove-object-properties)
- [babel-plugin-remove-attribute](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-remove-attribute)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue while using `styled-components`. This is the solution I found to be most straight forward to me without using a HOC or Babel plugins.

I created a function which checks for a specific environment and then returns the value you pass to it, or `undefined`. If the attribute value is `undefined` the attribute wont be included.

```
export const ifDev = val => (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? val : undefined);
```

Then in your components:

```
import { ifDev } from './dev';

<div className="sc-fMiknA" data-app-feature={ifDev("element-id")}></div>
```

Now I can find elements in browser tests while using generated class names and the attributes won't be included in production builds.

Comment: Note: The attributes won't appear in the DOM, but they're still present in the JS source files that produce the DOM. (the question is vague regarding this matter, so your answer is still great! I'm mentioning it just in case someone reads that and actually wants to reduce their bundle size).

Answer (score -3):

you can use selenium to do so:

```
WebElement yourElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath to element"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('data-app-feature','example-id')",yourElement);
```

Answer (score -10):

Create a tool that removes the attributes (a few lines of code) and tun that tool in the post build action.